# Wordpress Category Link get_category_link(id)

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

I need to link to a category in my wordpress site. The following code works, somewhat:

```
                <?php
 // Get the ID of a given category
 $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'People' );

 // Get the URL of this category
 $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
    ?>
```

My problem is that it includes /category/ in the url, which isn't how my permalink structure is designed. Does anyone know a way around including /category/ in the url it outputs?

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you using?

Comment: I found a plugin that addressed the problem in older wordpress installations. It was not updated for 2.9: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pathless-category-links/

Comment: Your approach is actually correct. The category URI includes the category base, which for custom taxonomies is defined within the 'rewrite' portion of the taxonomy definition, but for the built-in 'category' taxonomy, you can change this within the Admin panel: Settings > Permalinks > Category Base. If you have created a custom rewrite rule in your htaccess that excludes the category base, then you can't use `get_category_link()` but must roll your own, which could go something like: `echo site_url( $term->slug )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you want to do. Look here [Template Tags/wp list categories « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) for the template tag for category menus that will include whatever category base you have set. If you want to output the link to a category on the category page itself, then use:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>" title="<?php echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>">

<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->category_description; ?></a>
```

Comment: Was brain dead and didn't consider that solution. There is a built in "link to category" tag, but it automatically prepends the link with garbage. Thx!

Comment: I should note that if the permalink structure changes, then these urls will break. Using the category link tag, it will maintain linkage.

Comment: Right; the wordpress functions will regardless of permalink settings and with the plugin no-category-base, too...

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that does work with 2.9:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

I'm going to leave the question open, though, for those who may know how to solve the problem without a plugin.